# double click on selectbox impossible on modern browsers?

Tags: javascript, html, double-click

I'm dumbstruck...

It would seem that you can not trigger a double click event on a single line selectbox in modern browsers... I've been able to do this on 'old' IE8, but when upgrading a webapp to IE 10 it this just stopped working... Also testen FF, same problems.

check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vLnA2/

```
<SELECT ondblclick="go()">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</SELECT>
```

Comment: `click` handlers on `<select>` elements have never been a good idea. What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: That is the behavior for select option. Besides what purpose would double click serve here ?

Comment: Double click doesn't work on OPTION, it only works on SELECT.

Comment: Ok, I understand that my reasons for wanting to do this are unclear:
In my application the user can 'lock' an input field so it retains it value after the form has been ajax submitted. The 'locking' was done be double clicking the control (it than also changed appearance so the user could see).
I'm now rebuilding the logic by using a small hover-over item that will do this... But out of pure curiosity I would like to know WHY double clicks on select items don't work anymore...

Answer (score 1):

What is it your trying to do?

You would be better of using the following (JQuery):

```
$('#myItem').change(function(){
     //do somthing
})
```

Comment: Hey jamie, please see my response to the comments above. thanks for the kind suggestion though!

Comment: @palloquin Just updated my answer as your JsFiddle is working on the above modern browsers.

Comment: WTF? Are you sure you tested clicking the BOTTOM selectbox (the single line one)???
I've tested using both IE10 and FF 25.0

Comment: My mistake I thought this was related to the multi-select box, sorry been looking at another question on select boxes!